# UTF -8 issue in Datastxa Cassandra

Tags: php, python, solr, cassandra, datastax

I am using Datastax Cassandra 4.8 version. Using SOlr for Search activity. In my table , I have chinese character as well as English character. 
Table retrieval is workign smooth for english character search but once I am trying to search by Chinese character , either it gave me 0 row or give me below error.

```
cqlsh:tradebees_dev> select title,isbn,id,author from tradebees_dev.yf_product_books where solr_query = 'author:[英丽]朱莉娅·唐纳森';
'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 106-107: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Please suggest me how to correct it. Is any configuration section where I have to enable any thing.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the author column is configured to use an `ascii` data type. I'm not familiar with Datastax Cassandra, so I couldn't tell you how to change it, but I think if you change it to datatype `varchar` it should work.

Sorry for the kinda generic answer, but hope it helps anyway.

Comment: thanks for your reply.. Varchar is not used in Cassandra.. In Cassandra we use text data type. I can able to insert but not able to retrieve..

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have run into [CASSANDRA-10875](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10875). This was fixed in 2.0.13. You don't say which version of 4.8 you are running but I would suggest updating to the latest version of 4.8 where this issue should be fixed.

Comment: Can you please specify me for what version are you asking ? I am using DSE 4.8.9 Cassandra 2.1.15.1403 cqlsh 5.0.1

Comment: Can you confirm that cqlsh has the following at line 952:            self.lastcmd = raw_input(prompt).decode(self.encoding)

Comment: Sorry but in my Datastax,I am not able to find cqlsh.py file. Can you please suggest me in which file I have to look for this.

Comment: I checked in file which is in location /usr/share/dse/resources/cassandra/bin/cqlsh
------------------------------
def get_input_line(self, prompt=''):
        if self.tty:
            self.lastcmd = raw_input(prompt).decode(self.encoding)
            line = self.lastcmd + '\n'
as you tell me , this is present in this file.. in same order. 
Now please suggest me what I have to do ?